# I coudn't output the variable I create in javascript. I want to output it inside a text

Tags: javascript, php

It's working if I use document.write("**" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "**"); But I want to output it inside a textbox. I tried already creating a var then getting it but nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
}

document.getElementById("time").value = ("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>");
</script>
```

MY HTML CODE:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Time">Time: </label>
    <input style="margin-left: 50px;" name="time" id="time" type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline" readonly>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //Your code
  });`

Comment: That works. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Where is your script placed, before or after the textbox? The script should be placed after the element

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

  if (minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  var suffix = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) {
  suffix = "PM";
  hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (hours == 0) {
  hours = 12;
  }
  document.getElementById("time").value = ("" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "");
  });
```